# Change default font in MS word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I don't believe this has been asked before, and I'm curious,

Is there any way to change the default font in MS Word 2010 beta? Or MS Word 2007?

I'm getting really tired of changing fonts every time I write a document. I simply don't like the Calibri font and change it every time... and it's getting annoying.

Thanks.

Comment: Wow... Thanks for replying. All of these work. It's not possible to accept three answers is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way:

- On the ribbon there is a little arrow icon in the bottom right of the font settings box

  [image]
- In the resulting dialog box change your settings and then click the Default button

  [image]

Comment: This one is quickest to implement (to change the default font) although all the other answers are also very useful; thus I've selected it as answer. I've voted the other answers up too since they also provide a way to change more than just the default font, a bonus. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  All you need to do is change the style/font, in you toolbar's *Change Styles* option.  Change the font, color, or even style set, and then set as default. When you restart word, your font should be ready to go.  See Image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Windows XP**: Goto `C:\Documents and Settings\_YOUR_USER_NAME_\Application Data\Microsoft\Templates`

**Windows Vista / Windows 7**: Goto `C:\Users\_YOUR_USER_NAME_\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

Right click on `Normal.dotm` and choose `Open` instead of `New`

Modify font in `Normal` Style. After you're done, click `Save`

Bingo!

Comment: My "set as default" button didn't do squat but this worked like a dream. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found out coincidentally although it's too much work :-)

Click in the ribbon on the 2th style icon 'no spacing' , type two or three lines in the document, mark the lines and click right to change font and or line distance and click ok.

Click right again on your marked text lines, click right again to change font / line distance and click save as default, do that three times!

After three times clicking on 'save as default' your settings are saved as default!